# Python sequence naming convention

Tags: python, naming-conventions, sequence

Since there is no explicit typing in python, I want to be able to make the difference between sequences and non-sequences using a naming convention. I have been programming with python for a little while now, and I still haven't found any logical/practical way to name sequences. Of course, I went through the famous [PEP8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), and made some research on google, and it seems that the accepted convention is to add the letter "s" at the end of the variable name.

Let's assume we have a sequence of "weight values", therefore the variable name for the sequence should be *weights*. So far that's fine, but there will be cases where some word ends with "s" and happen to be the more logical way to name a variable which is not a sequence. Or let's say you have sequences of weights themselves stored into a sequence. The "s" naming convention would name the variable *weightss*, which is ugly. I am sure there is be a better naming convention for sequences.

What naming convention for sequences would you advise?

Comment: What was wrong with "weight_seq" as a name for a sequence of weights?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In general, avoid this kind of behaviour. Notice from [PEP8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

> A Foolish Consistency is the Hobgoblin
>   of Little Minds

which is exactly what calling a variable `weightss` would be doing. So in general have your variables describing what they are, not according to some naming convention:

```
weights = [44, 66, 88]
weight_groups = [[44, 66, 88], ...]
```

etc.

From the same section of the [PEP8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/):

> But most importantly: know when to be
>   inconsistent -- sometimes the style
>   guide just doesn't apply.  When in
>   doubt, use your best judgment.  Look
>   at other examples and decide what
>   looks best.  And don't hesitate to
>   ask!

Comment: The paragraph that starts with the above quote ends with "To be great is to be misunderstood." http://www.emersoncentral.com/selfreliance.htm Therefore great answers on SO are doomed to be downvoted :)

Comment: I've added another quote from the PEP8. Feel free to rollback

Answer (score 10):

> The "s" naming convention would name the variable weightss, which is ugly. I am sure there is be a better naming convention for sequences.

I think the convention you're describing is meant to be interpreted as "whenever you have list of something, make it clear that it's a list by pluralizing it". For example, if you have a list of instances of grass, you would call this `grasses`, not `grasss`. I don't think it's meant to be taken as literally as you're taking it.

PEP always advises you to take your own approach if that is more readable and useful. As [**Ali mentioned**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/659415/python-sequence-naming-convention/659439#659439), one of the guiding principles of PEP is that you shouldn't fall prey to foolish consistencies.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever you little heart desires....

Just kidding, but I wouldn't get to hung up on it.  If it's ugly, do something to make it more readable like `seq_weight` and `seq_weights`

Answer (score 0):

Why not just `thing_list` or `thing_seq`?

Comment: My biggest reason would be that it's a leaky abstraction of a name (list is only one kind of sequence). Otherwise not too bad, though. weights plural of weights, weights_list or weights_group or whatever as plural of weights.

Comment: That's what I begun with, but then I went back to the "s" convention. The problem is that if you decide to switch from a list implementation to a dictionary implementation, the "_list" suffix will no longer match what's inside.

Comment: What's wrong with thing_seq as a generalization of thing_list?

Comment: I like thing_seq just fine too

Comment: But with this convention, a sequence of sequences would have to be named thing_seq_seq. One could just name it thing_seq, but then there would be no difference between sequences and sequences of sequences, and the problem would be the same than with the "plural convention" discussed above.