# Proper naming conventions for a dictionary in Python

Tags: python, dictionary, naming-conventions, naming

After having someone read through my code, I noticed they got confused by the name of a variable containing a dictionary. The variable was named after the purpose of the keys in the dictionary, not the values, which made them confused. This made me wonder if the "correct" way to name dictionaries is after the keys, values or both?

Comment: What do the keys and values represent in this case?

Answer (score 5):

It makes more sense to name the dictionary after the values it contains. This is how you would name a list of items. It's also similar to how you would name a function returning a value, namely you choose a name which describes the returned value rather than its parameters. When you see the expression `foo["bar"]` you want to know what it represents.

Let's say we have a dictionary of words and definitions. If we name the dictionary after the keys it would be something like `words["bar"]` and if we name it after the values it would be `definitions["bar"]`. I think most people would agree that the latter makes more sense.

Another strategy is to use *key_to_value* or *value_for_key* (or their plural form) which for the example above would be `word_to_definition` and `definition_for_word` respectively. Personally I prefer the conciseness of simply `definitions`.

Answer (score 2):

I think the following link might help you:
[Python Naming Conventions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2405958/python-naming-conventions-for-dictionaries-maps-hashes#:%7E:text=In%20python%20parlance%2C%20dict%20is,and%20user%20as%20the%20value.)

In a nutshell: there is no convention, just give your variables proper names so that when people read through your code, they know what its purpose is.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe share the dictionary to make the question a bit clearer?

I'm not convinced there is a "correct" way to do this (or that that idea really applies to programming in general). Yes, Python has this idea of `There should be one--and preferably only one--obvious way to do it.`, but that doesn't hold for a lot of things.

I'd probably lean towards keys, but the question is complicated by the fact that dictionaries can contain non-uniform data, so the keys might not represent the same sorts of things.

Your best bet is to aim to make your code easy to read and understand—give things names that describe what they are/contain, name functions for what they do, et cetera. The idea of [self-documenting code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-documenting_code#:%7E:text=Self%2Ddocumenting%20code%20is%20ostensibly,numberOfWords%20or%20TryOpen.) is useful here.